# can someone please send some test ether

Tags: testnets

can someone please send some test ether.i have been trying last 2 weeks but somehow mining not working on testnet. thanks dsyed

0xB8017ed5b72fA08605EBF39Ee6433DD559c02f68

Comment: Done. http://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xfb9de5154a731f05e8737ef8c608e72a122d34b127a25e918056c7365152ab72

Answer (score 1):

If you would like free Test-Net Ether, try out [Ethereum wei faucet](https://zerogox.com/ethereum/wei_faucet). All you need to do is provide your public address and they will send you a small amount of Ether automatically.

Also, although the Ethereum community is generous towards developers/testers, you should still figure out *why* you're unable to mine blocks. But Ether way you need some coin, so [here you go.](http://testnet.etherscan.io/block/0x900cefe8a664d78426279613cb3c802cdc2c5640244e94b2bd59fc9572642902)

Comment: We have made another faucet. You can tap it 1 ether / minute. http://ipfs.b9lab.com:8080/ipfs/QmWBRdUQsLahC8dWVo3rS9jrFnxGSw3WHm5gcHu3URTv87/throttled_faucet.html

Comment: Awesome tool! And thanks for referencing b9lab, @XavierLeprêtreB9lab, looks like a promising site for official blockchain courses. Donated 50ETH for the cause.

Comment: Website down, Error 502